# remote save onblur after edit using Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing

Tags: javascript, extjs, cell, gridpanel

I need to send the request (the store is using a **restproxy**) to my server **onblur**. I already have the save method working calling this from a button.

This is my **cellEditing**

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
    });

    grid.plugins = [cellEditing];
    grid.on('edit', function(editor, e) {
        // commit the changes right after editing finished
        e.record.commit();
        e.grid.store.save();

    });
```

I've read in the official doc that this is the needed event, however it seems to me that it is fired before editing.

### In short

1. What is the event that I have to bind after the cell was edited ?
2. Is it fine to use the `e.grid.store.save()` to send the request ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was calling both methods `commit` and `save`.

record.commit is cleaning the `dirty` flag, so store.save doesn't find anything to `sync`.

working sample:

```
var cellEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
        clicksToEdit: 1,
    });

    grid.plugins = [cellEditing];
    grid.on('edit', function(editor, e) {
        // commit the changes right after editing finished
        e.grid.store.save();

    });
```